# Send an outbound POST request using HTTPS on Openshift/Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, openshift

It seems like all outbound requests (e.g. `http.request(…)`, `restify.post(…)`) send to an `https://` URL are being converted to `http://` for some reason (OpenShift proxying?). How can I call an external API and make sure I hit the HTTPS URL instead of the HTTP one?

Here's a concrete example. This call to the StubHub API works perfectly when I run it from `localhost`, but as soon as I run it in an OpenShift or Heroku NodeJS container/dyno, I get forced to `http://api.stubhub.com/` and accordingly get an error.

```
var express = require('express'),
    server  = express(),
    fetch   = require('node-fetch')
    qs      = require('qs');

// api
var api = express.Router();
server.use('/api/v1', api);

api.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    fetch('https://api.stubhub.com/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic <TOKEN>',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: qs.stringify({
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: req.query.username,
            password: req.query.password,
            scope: 'PRODUCTION',
        }),
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            res.send(response.json());
        });
});

// server
server.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT || 3030, process.env.NODE_IP || 'localhost');
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The same error you get by visiting [http://api.stubhub.com/login](http://api.stubhub.com/login) (no `https`) in a browser: **Access Denied** (Code 403: Forbidden)

Comment: @MurraySmith, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I don't think so. It was a while ago so I don't recall exactly, but I think I had a legnthy email exchange with StubHub API support only to realize their API isn't well designed for what I want to do. I think I ended up having to buy a dedicated virtual server to host my app on... :/