# How to cURL an `https://` URL from OpenShift container

Tags: api, curl, https, openshift

Following up on [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142296/send-an-outbound-post-request-using-https-on-openshift-heroku), I realized that even if I SSH into my OpenShift container and attempt to manually cURL an HTTPS URL, it seems to get internally re-routed to the HTTP equivalent. How can I actually access the HTTPS version?

From my local machine:

```
$ curl -X POST -H “Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>” -H “Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded” -H “Content-Length: 0” https://api.stubhub.com/login
{”error”:”invalid_request”,”error_description”:”Missing grant_type parameter value”}
```

And from my remote machine (via SSH):

```
> curl -X POST -H “Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>” -H “Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded” -H “Content-Length: 0” https://api.stubhub.com/login
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access “http&#58;&#47;&#47;api&#46;stubhub&#46;com&#47;login” on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;63de6bd1&#46;1459386064&#46;30c676b
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note the `http` URL in the latter's response body.

(And of course, I'm using a working/tested `<TOKEN>`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should contact stubhub and see if they are blocking the ip address(es) that you are attempting the connection from.  I am able to curl other https url's from OpenShift Online without any issues.

Comment: After posting this I also tried cURLing other HTTPS URLs and was also successful so yes, it seems this is a StubHub issue. I have contacted their API Support email and am currently awaiting a response.